# Registering same singleton for multiple interfaces in IOC

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a service that needs to be able to handle native assets and attribute types, so I have a core service in my PCL called `BaseThemeService` which implements interface `IThemeService`.  I need to be able to access some attributes from the core PCL, which is why it implements the `IThemeService` from the core PCL.

Within each platform project, I have a class `ThemeService` which implements `IDroidThemeService` and extends `BaseThemeService`.  I then register the `IDroidThemeService` singleton in the setup of each project manually.

This works, except that there are now 2 instances of `BaseThemeService`.  1 that is registered for the `IThemeService` for the core, and 1 that is registered for the `IDroidThemeService` for the platform.

To work around this I construct it myself and then register each appropriately:

```
protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    ThemeService themeService = new ThemeService(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>(), Mvx.Resolve<IMvxResourceLoader>());
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDroidThemeService>(themeService);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IThemeService>(themeService);

    base.InitializeFirstChance();
}
```

This seems like it should work, but it doesn't since the `IMvxJsonConverter` and `IMvxResourceLoader` services have not been registered yet.

I see in the MvvmCross documentation that auto-loading using lazy construction will register a service with all implemented interfaces.  Is there a way to use that functionality here to remove the manual registration?

---

## Answer

```
protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDroidThemeService>(GetThemeService);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IThemeService>(GetThemeService);

    base.InitializeFirstChance();
}

private DroidThemeService DroidSingletonService = null;
private DroidThemeService GetThemeService()
{
    if (DroidSingletonService == null)
    {
        DroidSingletonService = Mvx.IocConstruct<DroidThemeService>();
    }
    return DroidSingletonService;
}
```

This ended up being the ultimate resolution.  I know the `RegisterAsLazySingleton` looks to solve this problem automatically, so I'll update again if I find a way to implement this that is slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a factory for the singleton which can produce a singleton manually and return that whenever anyone wants to call it. [See the docs for Lazy Singleton Registration](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control)

```
ThemeService singletonService = null;
private ThemeService GetThemeService() 
{
    if (singletonService == null) 
    {
        singletonService = new ThemeService(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>(), Mvx.Resolve<IMvxResourceLoader>());
    }
    return singletonService;
}

protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDroidThemeService>(GetThemeService);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IThemeService>(GetThemeService);

    base.InitializeFirstChance();
}
```

Depending on your situation, it may be appropriate for the field and method to be static.

Comment: This fixes the issue of resolving dependencies before they are registered.

Comment: BTW: you can use Mvx.IoCConstruct<ThemeService>(). This calls the constructor and automatically resolves the parameters instead of manually calling Resolve<T>() for each.

Comment: There is a `MvxLazySingletonCreator` helper inside CrossCore if that helps - see the code in  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxTypeExtensions.cs#L186

Comment: It seems like the API for registering a single instance against multiple interfaces is not directly supported by the auto generation tools.  Looks like a good project for a pull request though.